# C# - Why can't I use ternary operation inside string?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, ternary-operator, c#-6.0

I'm trying to write

```
$"This is { awesomeEnough ? "awesome" : "not awesome"}"
```

but I'm getting compiler error

> CS1003    Syntax error, ':' expected

is it expecting behavior or bug?

Comment: The `:` delimits the expression from the formatting in interpolated strings so you have to force it to not think it's that delimiter by put the expression inside parenthesis `$"This is { (awesomeEnough ? "awesome" : "not awesome")}"`

Answer (score 4):

Operator priority. Parenthesis should solve the problem

```
$"This is { (awesomeEnough ? "awesome" : "not awesome") }"
```

Comment: Was just about to say this, good solution!

Comment: The reason is not operator precedence - it's just that the colon gets interpreted as a separator for a format specifier